# shiny - I want to replace the button style with pictures by using introBox but not work

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I learn from the app="https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/scotpho-profiles.html" in RShiny gallery.

I want to realize the function of clicking on the picture to enlarge and jump.

But in my program, even the pictures cannot be displayed, and the path is ok. What is going on?

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  introjsUI(), # must include in UI
  mainPanel(
    introBox(
      div(class="landing-page-box",
          div("title_box", class = "landing-page-box-title"),
          div(class = "landing-page-icon", style= paste0("background-image: url(D:/chord_diagram.png);background-size: auto 80%; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;")),
          actionButton("btn", NULL, class="landing-page-button")),
      data.step = 1,
      data.intro = "hello"
    )
    
  )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtcars <- renderTable({
    head(mtcars)
  })
})
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes! You can see https://github.com/Public-Health-Scotland/scotpho-profiles-tool/issues/46